# Pass variable from controller to model (beforeSave) (Upload Field) CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, upload, cakephp-2.0

I really need to know this issue to finish my work.

Here I'll give a example envolving model and controller.
I want to pass $final_name from controller to beforeSave() of my model

```
public function admin_add() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->data['Client']['file']['tmp_name'] != '') {
                // Upload block
                $tmp_file = $this->data['Client']['file']['tmp_name'];
                $file = new File($tmp_file);
                if($file->mime() == "image/jpeg" or "image/png") {
                    $ext = explode('.', $this->data['Client']['file']['name']);
                    $name = md5($this->data['Client']['file']['name']);
                    $file->copy(IMG_DIR . 'portfolio\\' . $name . '.' . end($ext));
                    $final_name = $name . "." . end($ext); // File name with extension
                }
                // If save
            if($this->Client->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Client cadastrado com sucesso!', 'admin_flash');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my client model

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if($this->data['Client']['file']['name'] != null) {
        $this->data['Client']['file'] = $final_name;
    }
    return parent::beforeSave($options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Controller**

```
$this->request->data['Client']['final_name'] = $name . "." . end($ext);
```

**In Model**

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
if($this->data['Client']['file']['name'] != null) {
    $this->data['Client']['file'] = $this->data['Client']['final_name'];
}
return parent::beforeSave($options);
}
```

**Update for CakePHP3**

***Pass variable from controller to table beforeSave, afterSave ?***

```
// Examples
// In Controller
$this->Article->save($data, ['passVariable' => 'passedData']);

// in Table

public function beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
    {
        if (isset($options['passVariable'])) {
            // implement your code
        }
    }
```

**Read more:** https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_save

**But good place to modify data before save like asked in question are:**

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#before-marshal or
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators

Comment: Not working for me. Getting the following error : undefined property `data`. You have not defined the `data` association on

Comment: @rahim.nagori cakephp version?

Comment: @Salines it's 3.7.8